# POSIX shell script using a string to store command arguments

Tags: shell, git, sh

#### Background

I’ve started putting all my configuration files (which include many shell files) under version control.  In the Git repository, I’ve configured a *pre-commit* hook that runs the `checkbashisms` utility from Debian’s [devscripts package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/devscripts) on each `sh` file in the repository as a simple sanity check to ensure that I don’t inadvertently introduce Bash-specific syntax into scripts that should be POSIX compatible.

#### Reason for using POSIX sh

I’m using `/bin/sh` as the interpreter for this pre-commit hook as it’s quicker for systems where `/bin/sh` is a link to `dash`. Committing files shouldn’t take a noticeable amount of time.

I don’t want to run `checkbashisms` if the only files staged for committing are non-shell files and for performance, I only want to execute `checkbashisms` command once and supply as arguments the names of *all* the relevant files that should be checked.

#### Arguments that may contain spaces

While I don’t normally create files with names containing unusual characters, I tried to write this script to be reasonably robust (without becoming overly complex, harder to read and prone to error on various inputs).

In a more fully-featured shell such as Bash, I’d process a list of file name arguments using an array. However, a plain POSIX shell (such as dash) doesn’t support array variables.

#### My solution

When using a POSIX shell, the positional parameters can often be used as a substitute but in this case, I couldn’t see how I could easily modify them to only add the filenames of shell scripts.  The technique I used was to split fields using newlines (not spaces) and to use a string to store the arguments to be passed to `checkbashisms`.

I’ve verified that it works with filenames containing spaces and single quotes – but due to to how the shell represents names containing other characters, it doesn’t work with filenames containing double quotes, tabs, etc. This is fine as I really don’t expect to have to process such filenames.

However, it feels hacky and I don’t know if I’m introducing the potential for other errors (“unknown unknowns”). Modifying `IFS` is explicitly not recommended by [Greg’s Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments). I thought I’d post here in the hope that the robustness and/or maintainability of the code can be improved.

#### Script

```
#!/bin/sh

# Check shell scripts for Bashisms if the `checkbashisms` utility is installed.
# Called by "git commit" with no arguments.  This hook should exit with a
# non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if it wants to stop the
# commit.
# Allows for files with spaces or single quotes in their name – but not any
# other unusual characters.

set -u  # -o nounset – exit with failure if an unset shell variable is referenced.
set -e  # -o errexit – exit script if any command fails.
set -o noclobber  # prevent shell redirection from over-writing files.

if ! command -v checkbashisms >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "‘checkbashisms’ is not available; it can be installed from the ‘devscripts’ package."
else
  echo "Checking for Bashisms in shell scripts..."

  # Use only newline characters (not spaces) to split filenames.
  IFS="
"  # POSIX way to set IFS to newline (be careful with indentation).
  set -f  # Disable globbing of pathnames.
  # Arrays are not defined by POSIX so store arguments in a string variable.
  filenames=""

  # Get list of filenames that have been staged for committing.
  for file in $(git diff --cached --name-only); do
    # Only process shell scripts.
    case "$file" in *.sh|shell/*.sh)
      # Add file to list of arguments (separated by newlines).
      filenames="$filenames
$file"  # again, be careful with indentation of the code.
    esac
  done;

  # If any shell files have been staged, check their syntax for Bashisms.
  if [ "$filenames" ]; then
    if checkbashisms $filenames; then   # no quotes for field-splitting.
      printf "(No Bashisms found)"
    else
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

  # Restore file globbing and IFS.
  unset IFS
  set +f
fi

# Further code to check for other issues ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, you could turn the check if the `checkbashisms` tool is installed into a guard clause, shaving off one level of indentation:

```
if ! command -v checkbashisms >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "‘checkbashisms’ is not available; it can be installed from the ‘devscripts’ package."
    exit 1
fi
```

The remaining logic can be simplified a lot with the `xargs` tool.

```
if git diff --cached --name-only | grep "\\.sh$" | xargs checkbashisms; then
    printf "(No Bashisms found)"
else
    exit 1
fi
```

I understand that the code you showed it only part of a bigger script and you still want to use the generated list of files. However, calling `git diff` repeatedly will have negligible overhead and you can wrap the code in a shell function like this:

```
staged_scripts() {
    git diff --cached --name-only | grep "\\.sh$"
}

staged_scripts | xargs checkbashisms
```

Or even

```
check_staged_scripts() {
    git diff --cached --name-only | grep "\\.sh$" | xargs $1
}

check_staged_scripts "checkbashisms"
```

Comment: Thanks Anselm, that’s a great review. I’ve since modified my script somewhat but your answer is still applicable. I like your `xargs` pipeline – it’s much more elegant than the for loop with its conditional statements.  BTW, I see you only recently joined the Stack Exchange network so I’d like to say, “Wilkommen”.

Comment: Dankeschön! It was my pleasure.

Comment: Just pointing out that some people sometimes name bash files `.bash` , so I would add that to the valid file extension regex.